# playwright-python fails with "Navigation failed because page was closed!"

Tags: playwright, playwright-python

I have multiple pages to scrape with Playwright, but my script keeps failing with `playwright._impl._api_types.Error: Navigation failed because page was closed!`.

Here is my code:

```
urls = ['http://www.google.co.uk'] * 30
with sync_playwright() as p:
    browser = p.chromium.launch(headless=True)
    page = browser.new_page()
    for i, url in enumerate(urls):
        print(i, url)
        page.goto(url)
        headers = page.query_selector_all('h1')
    page.wait_for_timeout(30000)
    browser.close()
```

But this errors after a few seconds on the `page.goto` step, with the following error:

```
playwright._impl._api_types.Error: Navigation failed because page was closed!
=========================== logs ===========================
navigating to "url", waiting until "load"
```

It doesn't take 30 seconds to error though, so it isn't that the page has timed out.

How should I be doing this? Why has the page closed?

Comment: It's hard to say without the site(s) you're navigating to because the code looks totally normal. Does it fail on all sites or just some? Chances are, you're being detected as a bot.

Comment: This bug reproduces for me if I just replace the list of URLs with `google.co.uk`. I've updated with code that reproduces the same failure, typically after 5-15 requests.

Comment: Ah - I tried this with Firefox instead (`p.firefox.launch(headless=True)`) and it worked perfectly. So I think there is a bug in my Playwright Chromium setup. Thanks for looking.

Comment: It could also be the way a certain page is handled. If you narrow it down to one URL feel free to share it. Maybe FF handles it differently?

Comment: It's a browser issue. Cold Turkey Blocker (a web blocker tool) was auto-closing Chromium because it didn't have Cold Turkey extensions installed. It was doing the same with Firefox Nightly too, just less fast.

Comment: Feel free to post a [self answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) if you have it figured out.

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove the timeout value. It may be possible that a site takes 29.5 seconds to load or even 29.99 and because you are very close to the threshold you set - it is being rounded to full 30 seconds. Or, set the timeout to a really long time like 90,000 milliseconds.

```
urls = ['http://www.google.co.uk'] * 30
with sync_playwright() as p:
    browser = p.chromium.launch(headless=True)
    page = browser.new_page()
    for i, url in enumerate(urls):
        print(i, url)
        page.goto(url)
        headers = page.query_selector_all('h1')    
    browser.close()
```